# How do I use GSL in Julia?

Tags: julia, gsl

the general questión would be how do I to use any library non-standar in Julia, e.g. libraries exported from C, specifically I downloaded the GNU Scientific Library from https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/, according the Julia Manual I think it can be used, but I readed the INSTALL file from the GSL folder and I tried follow the steps, however I could not finish them because  I did'nt understand some steps.

If anyone could give me some advice to use this library in Julia,  I would appreciate it very much.

some details.

-OS: Windows10
-Julia version: 0.6

Comment: I really want familiarize myself with this, since I have a thesis in development and I would want Know how I do to handle external libraries, exported from C principally.

Comment: [Here's a blog post explaining how to wrap GSL functions with the C FFI](http://www.stochasticlifestyle.com/using-julias-c-interface-utilize-c-libraries/).

Comment: In general for C/Fortran libraries (but in this specific case better solutions exists, as in the Lyndon White answer) you first need to install (and even compile it if no precompiled versions exists for your system) the library on your system and then you can use it in Julia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the general case,
calling compiled code is done using [`ccall`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/)

For the case of GSL, for most operations you shouldn't be using GSL.
The (almost all) the functionality provided by GSL is well covered by the Julia standard library or by well maintained julia packages.
Mostly with implementation in pure julia.

Pure julia implementations will normally be basically as fast as the C/Fortran implementations.
Plus they will have other good features like working well with the optimiser,
and supporting custom types via multiple dispatch
For example supporting Dual numbers means that ForwardDiff.jl will just natively allow Auto differentiation to work with them.
For some code [ducktyping will even let them work with things like TensorFlow.](http://white.ucc.asn.au/2017/05/04/Plain-Functions-that-Just-Work-with-TensorFlow.jl.html).

As to how to install GSL, I think that is a seperate question from how to use GSL with julia.
Conviently though, if you are in a position you absolutely need to call GSL from julia,
there is already a julia package wrapping it. **[GSL.jl](https://github.com/JuliaMath/GSL.jl)**
And particularly conveniently, it will automatically download and install GSL for you when you run `Pkg.add("GSL.jl")`,
so you don't have to worry about installing it yourself.
If the package isn't working for you, raise an issue on their repo.

(Julia packages tend to be good like that, just installing all their dependencies so you don't have to fiddle around with things. I've been really impressed a few times when colleges have come to me saying "I love R library Foo but I can't using it on windows as I can't get the Fortran backend to work"; and I'll be like "Foo.jl does the same thing using the same fortran backend, also it automatically installs that backend, and does so in a way that just works even on windows.")